# Tkinter error: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-1"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a tic tac toe game and I am complete new into tkinter and python. I have a big problem with error mentioned in title "Tkinter error: _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-1"" and I want to know where it came from. I've checked all problems with similar error but I couldn't find the one like mine.
Below code creates a grid 3x3 and I've noticed that when I am clicking on buttons in first row the error is 'unknown option "-0"', when I am clicking on second row the error is
'unknown option "-1"' and when I am clicking on third row the error is  'unknown option "-2"'.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

'player user'
playerA = 'X'
'player computer using random'
playerB = 'O'

def change_button_value_after_click(r, c):
    if b['text'] == "":
        b[str(r)][str(c)] = playerA

    else:
        print("This button was clicked!")

'board creation'
board = [[col for col in range(3)] for row in range(3)]
for row in range(len(board)):
    for col in range(len(board[row])):
        b = Button(frame, text="", width=5,
        command=lambda r=row,c=col:change_button_value_after_click(r,c))
        b.grid(row=row, column=col)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it is because basically you are doing this `b['1']['1']` with every row, you are trying to access some attribute it doesn't have, `b` is a button, you can't create a button like this: `Button(1='some value')` first of because names starting with integers are not allowed and second because it has no such attribute, what are you trying to achieve? did you really mean to use `b` there?

Comment: I want to change the text value of button which was clicked from empty string to a variable playerA which is 'X'

Comment: so you want to actually use `board` which stores the buttons to be accessed by row and column: `if not board[r][c]['text']: board[r][c]['text'] = playerA`

Comment: it gives me this: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable ://

Comment: you need to add buttons to those lists

Comment: thanks! it works